# Detecting object boundaries on an image too slow

Tags: python, pandas, image-processing, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I have an `label_image`, as a dataframe that looks like this. Note that some objects, those labelled as `1` and `3` are completely engulfed/surrounded by other objects, there is not background separating the objects from each other. The `label_image` is given as an input here. I do not produce it myself as I do not have the actual image (as a tif, jpg, etc)

```
dummy_img = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
]))
```

I want to get the outlines of the objects.

What I had initially written was this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
from scipy.ndimage import binary_erosion

def outline(label_image):
    res_list = []
    
    mask = binary_erosion(label_image.values)
    label_image[mask] = 0
    c = coo_matrix(label_image)
    if c.data.size > 0:
        df = pd.DataFrame({'coords': list(zip(c.col, c.row)), 'label': c.data})
        df = df.groupby('label')['coords'].apply(lambda group_series: group_series.tolist()).reset_index()
        df = df.astype({"label": int})
    else:
        df = pd.DataFrame()
    return df
```

That gives as an output:

```
label   coords
2       [(3, 3), (4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 3), (7, 3), (8, 3...
4       [(12, 3), (13, 3), (14, 3), (15, 3), (16, 3), ...
```

which is wrong. Not only it misses the inner objects but the derived coords for the detected objects are wrong too. For `label 4` for example it returns the outline between `labels 4 and 0` and ignores the one between `labels 4 and 3`.

I did this fix

```
def outline_fix(label_image):
    res_list = []
    coo = coo_matrix(label_image)
    labels = np.unique(coo.data)
    for label in sorted(set(labels)):
        #print('label: %d' % label)
        c = coo.copy()
        c.data[c.data != label] = 0
        c = c.toarray()
        mask = binary_erosion(c)
        c[mask] = 0
        c = coo_matrix(c)
        if c.data.size > 0:
            df = pd.DataFrame({'coords': list(zip(c.col, c.row)), 'label': c.data})
            df = df.groupby('label')['coords'].apply(lambda group_series: group_series.tolist()).reset_index()
            df = df.astype({"label": int})
        else:
            df = pd.DataFrame()
        res_list.append(df)
        
    if res_list:
        out = pd.concat(res_list).astype({"label": int})
    else:
        out = pd.DataFrame()
        
    return out
```

which returns:

```
label   coords
1       [(5, 6), (6, 6), (7, 6), (8, 6), (9, 6), (5, 7...
2       [(3, 3), (4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 3), (7, 3), (8, 3...
3       [(12, 5), (13, 5), (14, 5), (10, 6), (11, 6), ...
4       [(12, 3), (13, 3), (14, 3), (15, 3), (16, 3), ...
```

which works fine. Not 100% perfect, since for example, for `label 4` it misses two pairs of coordinates. The list of coords should have length=32 not 30 that I get, but this is something I can live with, it is not very important.

The problem with the corrected function is that it is painfully slow. In a real case scenario I have an array which `2000-by-2000` with more than `2800` objects. Not all of the objects are "nested" but it can be quite many, depends on the image that comes in.

The code finishes (for a real real life case) in around 4 mins which is prohibitively long. Are there any alternatives please, or any ideas to speed this up maybe?

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: To do image processing, use an image processing library, don’t try to get a tool that wasn’t designed for it to do image processing. You can use scikit image, OpenCV, DIPlib, whatever. With the right tool this is a trivial task.

Comment: Thanks Chris, which function do you have in mind please? `binary_erosion` doesn't seem to work very well here.

Comment: Try **OpenCV** `findContours()`.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience pandas is quite slow when you have to use `.apply` function. For this reason I prefer to do operations on `.values` and then re-assign. Having said that, pandas can be made very fast, but it is an [art of its own](https://medium.com/bigdatarepublic/advanced-pandas-optimize-speed-and-memory-a654b53be6c2). Check this code, for large images it will most certainly be faster than pandas implementation:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

dummy_img = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
]))

# Array of boundary points
# row - label, col - point coordinates

img_np = dummy_img.values
b_pts = [[] for i in range(4)] 

# idea is simple - run a 3x3 window and check whenever the mean value
# inside the window differs from element at the center. 

img_padded = np.pad(img_np, ((1, 1), (1, 1)))
    
for r, row in enumerate(img_np):
  for c, elem in enumerate(row):
    if Flase in (img_padded[r:r+3, c:c+3] == elem):
      b_pts[elem-1].append((r, c))

for elem in b_pts:     
  print(elem)
```